# JSP + SQL (Using Like)

Tags: java, sql, jsp, servlets, sql-like

JSP File:

```
<form action="PatientsController?cmd=search" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search here.."
                        class="form-control text-box single-line">


   <select name="select">
        <option value="id">Id</option>
        <option value="name">Name</option>
        <option value="address">Address</option>
        <option value="cpf">Cpf</option>
        <option value="phone">Phone</option>
        <option value="birthDate">Birth Date</option>
        <option value="gender">Gender</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Servlet:

```
List<Patient> list = new PatientDao().indexFilter(
        request.getParameter("select"),
        request.getParameter("search"));
request.setAttribute("new", list);
request.getRequestDispatcher("Index.jsp")
        .forward(request, response);
```

PatientDAO:

```
public List<Patient> indexFilter(String attribute, String condition)
        throws Exception {
    open();

    ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM patients WHERE ? like ? ORDER BY id");
    ps.setString(1, attribute);
    ps.setString(2, "%" + condition + "%");
    rs = ps.executeQuery();

    List<Patient> list = new ArrayList<Patient>();

    while (rs.next())
        list.add(newPatientSetted());

    ps.close();

    close();
    return list;
}

private Patient newPatientSetted() throws Exception {
    return new Patient(rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3),
            rs.getString(4), rs.getString(5), rs.getDate(6), rs
                    .getString(7).equals("M") ? Gender.M : Gender.F);
}
```

So, I have a problem, I don't know but query is returning nothing (I debugged in DAO and it doesn't join in while loop - in other words, Result Set doesn't have next()), what am I doing wrong? If I remove the "?" after "Where" and put an attribute manually the LIKE operator works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL parameter is only allowed in places having sense 'value'. Is denied in place of table or column.

```
 "SELECT * FROM patients WHERE ? like ? ORDER BY id"  -- bad, field 'substitution' is not alowed

 "SELECT * FROM ? WHERE id like ? ORDER BY id"  -- bad, column is not alowed

 "SELECT * FROM patients WHERE Name like ? ORDER BY id"  -- OK,
```

Background. Lets imagine sql server prepare query tu achieve higher speed. Optimization with unknown column or field cannot be done. Its only image to better understand.

Strict: is denied by standard.

EDIT: extended aswer, how to achieve your target:

```
 String qry = "SELECT * FROM patients WHERE "+attribute +" like ? ORDER BY id";
 ps = con.prepareStatement(qry);
    ps.setString(1, "%" + condition + "%");
    rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Comment: My idea was supposedly like this: user could put some condition in the search "input" and select which field should be carried out the search, understand?

Comment: Since, you said it's not allowed, so I can't do this, right? Or is there another way?

Comment: Yes, I understand idea, general universal searcher. and this is OK, but not in such way. Must build sql string with column name, this cannot be parametrized by `?`

Answer (score 0):

When you prepare a statement, the database constructs an execution plan, which it cannot do if the table or column are not there. In other words, placehodlers can only be used for **values** not for object names or reserved words. You'd have to rely on Java to construct your string in such a case

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM patients WHERE "+attribute+" like ? ORDER BY id ";
ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, "%" + condition + "%");
rs = ps.executeQuery();
```